# How to sum over columns with some weight in a csr matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, sum, sparse-matrix

If I have a large csr_matrix A, I want to sum over its columns, simply
    `A.sum(axis=0)`
does this for me, right? Are the corresponding axis values: 1->rows, 0->columns?

I stuck when I want to sum over columns with some weights which are specified in a list, e.g. [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 ... 4 2 5] with the same length as the number of rows in the csr_matrix A. To be more clear, I want the inner product of each column vector with this weight vector. How can I achieve this with Python?

This is a part of my code:

```
uniFeature = csr_matrix(uniFeature)
[I,J] = uniFeature.shape
sumfreq = uniFeature.sum(axis=0)
sumratings = []

for j in range(J):
    column = uniFeature.getcol(j)
    column = column.toarray()
    sumtemp = np.dot(ratings,column)
    sumratings.append(sumtemp)

sumfreq = sumfreq.toarray()
average = np.true_divide(sumratings,sumfreq)
```

(Numpy is imported as np) There is a weight vector "ratings", the program is supposed to output the average rating for each column of the matrix "uniFeature".

I experimented to dot column=uniFeature.getcol(j) directly with ratings(which is a list), but there is an error that says format does not agree. It's ok after column.toarray() then dot with ratings. But isn't making each column back to dense form losing the point of having the sparse matrix and would be very slow? I ran the above code and it's too slow to show the results. I guess there should be a way that dots the vector "ratings" with each column of the sparse matrix efficiently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help a lot to post some code further communicating what your data looks like.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I was just being stupid. I should use matrix multiplication directly